# Calculate max Height of array

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm calculating the `max` height that is inserted in the applications, and it gives me a `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` error, the time of values inserted is the same of the length of the array including the 0 index, but i am still having this error.

```
int nrPersons = 3;
double[] height = new double[nrPersons];
double maxHeig = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= nrPersons; i++) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    in.useLocale(Locale.US);

    System.out.println("Insert Height");

    height[i] = in.nextDouble();

    if (height[i]> maxHeig)
        maxHeig = height[i];

}

System.out.println("The max Height is: "+maxHeig);
```

Comment: i<nrPersons instead of i<=nrPersons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
for (int i = 0; i <= nrPersons;i++){
```

You need to not have `i` ever reach the value of `nrPersons` as this will be out of bounds. Arrays in Java are indexed from `0` and have the number of elements defined. So for some array:

```
int[] i = new int[3];
i[0] = 0; //fine
i[1] = 0; //fine
i[2] = 0; //fine
i[3] = 0; //**ERROR** Out of bounds
```

Simple solution is to use this common syntax:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nrPersons; i++)
```

Comment: Of course, my bad, cant understand how could i missed it. Thanks @Kon